# ppolicy with openldap - pwdReset has no effect when logging in from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openldap, reset-password

We installed ppolicy overlay on our ldap server. Password policies work correctly for locking out user after X incorrect password attempts, but we can't enforce user to change his password.

When we set pwdReset attribute for a user - user can login as usual from Ubuntu client machine.

Ldap server & client were setup according to Ubuntu howto: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/openldap-server.html

How to make ubuntu client honor pwdReset attribute?

Answer (score 0):

The client has to use the password response connect control, and respond to it if present by requiring a password change in the application. It isn't automatic. The response control isn't included in JNDI but I posted code for it a year or so ago in the Oracle Java JNDI forum.

Comment: It's pretty basic thing... Isn't there some ubuntu package which will check pwdReset upon login and ask user to change a password if needed?